# Composite IF statement in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql stored procedure in which I want to write a composite If statement. Let a, b,c  be the variables then In what order the following if will execute.

```
  IF (a AND c=0) OR (b AND c=0) OR (!a AND !b) THEN
    execute the code....
```

The above If statement not working properly. Is there any problem in the statement?
 I actually want to know the  precedence of AND, OR operators.

Comment: `(a = 0 AND b = 0)`. Coding isn't quite the exact same as the English language.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
IF (a IS NOT NULL AND c=0) OR (b IS NOT NULL AND c=0) OR (a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NOT NULL) THEN
execute the code....
```

In SQL, `NULL` does not act like `FALSE`; SQL uses 3-state logic where an expression can be `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `NULL`, and all comparisons with `NULL` are `FALSE`. See the documentation [Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html).

Comment: No I want IF (a has value(not null) AND  c=0) OR (b has value(not null) AND  c=0) OR ( a has no value (null) AND b has no value (null))

Comment: The question _may_ be asking for `(a IS NOT NULL AND c=0)` etc., but it's certainly not clear.